# Avoiding vertical vectors in tangent spaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $i: [0,1]\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth embedding. Can I find arbitrary small perturbations $j$ of $i$ s.t. $j(0)=i(0)$, $j(1)=i(1)$ and $j'(t)$ is never a multiple of $(0,0,1)$?

More generally, if $i: N\hookrightarrow M\times [0,1]$ is an embedding of (compact if necessary) manifolds, $\dim N\leq \frac{1}{2}\dim M$, can I always find arbitrary small perturbations (wrt. some metric on $M$) $j$ of $i$ s.t.

- $i(x)=j(x)$ whenever $i(x)\in M\times \{0,1\}$
- $j_*(TN)$ never contains a vector $\partial_t$ in the "vertical" direction?

If necessary, consider just the second condition. I will appreciate a hint or reference to this kind of problems. (I need to project an ambient framed cobordism in $M\times [0,1]$ to $M$..)

---

Update: in the discussion below was proposed to consider the composition 
$$
j:N\stackrel{0}{\hookrightarrow} TN\stackrel{\iota}{\to} T(M\times [0,1])\stackrel{\pi}{\to} M\times [0,1]
$$
with $\iota$ some generic map whose image avoids the vertical distribution. However, the equation $dj=\iota$ doesn't hold in general (or at least I don't see it).

Comment: Do a helix. ${}{}$

Comment: Have you tried looking in some books on differential topology, like Hirsch's book? It's certainly amenable to transversality. You are trying to avoid a $\dim M+1$ dimensional submanifold (the vertical distribution) with a (basically) $2\dim(N)$-dimensional object while manoeuvring in a $2(\dim M+1)$-dimensional space. For dimensional reasons alone this will work, because generically the intersection of an $a$ dimensional thing with a $b$ dimensional thing in a $c$ dimensional thing is empty provided $c>a+b$, which is the case here. But you probably figured as much on your own and want proof ^^

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks for the comment and your time. I know I'm probably missing somethink very fundamental, but I cannot see the reduction to a problem on interections of manifolds and transversality. The "$2 \dim N$-dimensional object" you mean the tangent bundle? If I make a perturbation of the "tangent bundle" in the "tangent bundle of $M\times [0,1]$" and find an imbedding disjoint from the "vertical distribution", how do I know that what I've contructed is still the tangent bundle of something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a counting mistake. Let's write $m$ and $n$ for the dimensions of $M$ and $N$ respectively. $di$ maps $TN$ (a $2n$ dimensional manifold) into $T(M\times[0,1])$, a $2m+2$ dimensional manifold. What you are trying to avoid is the subbundle $\left\lbrace\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{(m,t)}:\lambda\in\Bbb R, m\in M,t\in[0,1]\right\rbrace$, which is a $m+1+1$ dimensional submanifold of $T(M\times[0,1])$. So taking $a=2n$, $b=m+2$ and $c=2m+2$, so actually $a+b=c$, and the intersection will generically be points.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat assume that $\dim N<(1/2) \dim M$ and it is possible. I believe that you can avoid the vertical subbandle by a submanifold in $T(M\times [0,1])$. What I don't see is why is it a tangent bundle of some submanifold $N'$. Is it a general statement that a perturbation of the tangent bundle is still a tangent bundle of some manifold?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is $N'$? The "vertical bundle" isn't a tangent bundle, it's just a vector subbundle of (the vector bundle) $T(M\times[0,1])$.

Comment: I don't see how this could fail when $2n=m$... at least in the case $n=1$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Ok, I think I got it. What you are saying is that you can -- because of dimensional reasons -- construct a perturbation $j_*$ of $i_*: TN\hookrightarrow T(M\times [0,1])$ that doesn't intersect the vertical distribution; and this determines an embedding $j: N\to M\times [0,1]$, right? I was probably just confused, now it looks too simple.

Comment: That's the point though: suppose $\iota$ is a perturbation of $di$, then you can define its "projection" $j=N\stackrel{0}{\hookrightarrow}TN\xrightarrow{\iota}T(M\times[0,1]) \xrightarrow{\pi}M\times[0,1]$, which will remain an embedding as long as $\iota$ is close to $di$, but you won't have $dj=\iota$. The problem is then that $dj$ might hit the vertical distribution, although I would venture to think generically it won't.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat So if I don't have $dj=\iota$, how can I find my desired $N\hookrightarrow M\times [0,1]$?

Comment: I think $j$ thus defined will generically work, but that's just my guess. I'm still hung up on the dimensional argument though...

Comment: I agree that the dimensional argument is not clear at this moment: in general, it seems that you would need one more dimension but in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it seems to work.. If you have an idea how to fix the $dj\neq \iota$, please tell me :)

Comment: We most certainly won't be able to fix $dj\neq\iota$, but I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: Something fishy is going on: if we consider the differential $di$ induces (by virtue of $i$ being an embedding) a map $\tilde{di}$ between the projective bundles, then $\tilde{di}$ sweeps out an $2n-1$ dimensional submanifold of the $2(m+1)-1$-dimensional projective bundle $P(T(M\times[0,1]))$, and we want it to miss an $m+1+1-1$-dimensional submanifold. Now $(2n-1)+(m+1+1-1)=2n+m<2m+1=(2m+2-1)$. So it should work fine even when $2n=m$.

Comment: Nice. But still there is this problem how to convert it to an embedding $N\hookrightarrow M\times [0,1]$.

Comment: Can't we use some form of Whitney embedding theorem here?